# x = x + y formula returning 0 in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

While running the following code the variable intEarn does not change from *0* when adding on a formula onto itself in the style of `intEarn = intEarn + (...)`.

I have placed message boxes throughout the code to see exactly what is being computed each time and for whatever reason it seems that the `intEarn = intEarn + (...)` always results in 0 no matter what is in the `(...)`.

```
Dim ovr As Range
Set ovr = cells.Find("Overview").Offset(2, 0)
Dim intEarn As Long
intEarn = 0

...

x = 0
Do until IsEmpty(ovr.Offset(x, 0))
        'The following line results in 0
        intEarn = intEarn + (ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 1).Value * ovr.Offset(x,0).Offset(0, 2).Value)
        'While the next line of code results in the proper number
        MsgBox ("Correct: " & ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 1).Value * ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 2).Value)
        x = x + 1
Loop
```

I expected the first output of `intEarn = intEarn + (ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 1).Value * ovr.Offset(x,0).Offset(0, 2).Value` to equal **0.327** since `ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 1).Value` = **1090** and `ovr.Offset(x, 0).Offset(0, 2).Value` = **.03%**.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with VBA, but is it because you are casting a float to an int somewhere? I've done this to myself several times.

Comment: Are you sure this is not the problem? `Do until IsEmpty(ovr.Offset(x, 0))`. That is the main suspect in my opinion

Comment: Try declaring `intEarn As Double` ...and drop Hungarian Notation ;-)

Comment: @kei Thanks for the speedy response, believe it or not that must've been exactly what was doing it. I changed Dim as Long to Double and works like a charm. Didn't think that was the case because I did the same thing very similarly in a different module, but that wasn't done it a loop. Thanks again!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Dim intEarn As Long
> ```

`Long` is a 32-bit integer type, it doesn't deal with decimals. So when the right-hand side of the assignment evaluates to 0.327, VBA merrily performs a narrowing conversion from `Double` to `Long`, and you get `0`.

Declare it as a `Double`, and the implicit narrowing conversion will no longer happen, the decimals will be preserved, and the code should run as intended.

Except `int` is a misleading prefix for a `Double`. Better avoid encoding a data type in the name.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! In my code int actually doesn't stand for integer, however I now see that it could come across that way and went ahead and changed it to be more clear.